# Do animals exist that grow body parts back into themselves?

Tags: morphology

goats sometimes grow their horns in a way that it "grows back" into its skull (e.g., https://en.goodtimes.my/2017/11/27/argali-sheeps-majestic-spiral-horns-can-protect-kill/).
However, this is a rare defect and not the "intended" way for the goat to grow, since it seriously hurts the animal.

I wonder, are there any organisms in which body parts merge with another part (as opposed to growing out of another part, as is standard) in this way, where it is not a mistake and instead a feature of the organism?

Thanks!

Comment: Would [babirusa[(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babirusa) count?

Comment: Does a narwhal count?

Comment: Human infants have 270~300 pcs of bones, that merge into 206 pcs in adults.